# Rollup values between numbers > zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table of which I want to get a count between the numbers > 0. Given the table I would like to see the results of value > 0 in columns and the count of 0.0 records until the next number > 0.

Example

| value | customer_id | count of 0.00 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23.0000 | 1 | 2 |
| 10.00 | 1 | 3 |
| 27.0000 | 2 | 3 |

Table of data

| value | created_at | id | customer_id | order_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23.0000 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.0000 |  | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 0.0000 |  | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 0.0000 |  | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 10.0000 |  | 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 0.0000 |  | 6 | 1 | 6 |
| 0.0000 |  | 7 | 1 | 7 |
| 0.0000 |  | 8 | 1 | 8 |
| 0.0000 |  | 9 | 2 | 9 |
| 0.0000 |  | 10 | 2 | 10 |
| 27.0000 |  | 11 | 2 | 11 |
| 0.0000 |  | 12 | 2 | 12 |
| 0.0000 |  | 13 | 2 | 13 |
| 0.0000 |  | 14 | 2 | 14 |

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a variation of the *gaps-and-islands* problem. The general solution is to calculate a running count of the special-case rows ("gaps"), group-by that running count value (which groups the data into "islands"), and finally figure the desired results from there.

I believe the following will accomplish your task:

```
WITH GroupedData AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN value > 0 THEN 1 END)
            OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY id)
            AS Grp
    FROM Data
)
SELECT
    MAX(value) AS value,
    customer_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 END) AS [count of 0.00] -- or COUNT(*)-1
FROM GroupedData
GROUP BY customer_id, Grp
HAVING MAX(value) > 0 -- Exclude leading zero groups
ORDER BY customer_id, Grp
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qt8E3KWL) for a demo.